# Configuring controller but getting error ActionNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am I configuring the default route correctly? Currently my route is set to:

```
root :to => 'proto#index'
```

When I do I am receiving the following error:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'index' could not be found for ProtoController):
```

What file do I need to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for **app/controllers/proto_controller.rb**

It should contain something like the following

```
class ProtoController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

end
```

Then you want to make a file at **app/views/proto/index.html.erb** that contains the html for the page.

Comment: It's been a while since you needed to create a dummy action in order your route to work. Make just a view, it should be enough.

Comment: @jdoe That's fair, but the OP is pretty new to Rails, and I thought it might make things a little clearer to just show the method.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you should check.

Do you have a controller called "proto"?

If so, do you have `index` action in your proto controller?

Ideally, your proto controller should be something like ..

```
class ProtoController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @protos = Proto.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is `app/controllers/proto_controller.rb`

And rails convention is to pluralize model name in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

`root :to => 'proto#index'` should go in config/routes.rb

ProtoController should be defined in app/controllers/proto_controller.rb

```
class ProtoController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

This action will look for the template defined by app/views/proto/index.html.erb and render it out.