# Deploying Rails on AWS elastic beanstalk - Static Asset routing not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I put up my rails application on AWS elastic beanstalk through Amazon's eb tool.
On elastic beanstalk, I'm using its default load balancer, and am running ubuntu 64bit with ruby 2.0.

I'm getting two major problems:

1) the root route isn't working.

- In my config/routes.rb, I tried:

  > root 'controller#action
  >   root :to => 'controller#action'
  >   root to: 'controller#action'

  and found none of them working. The server was giving me an error saying that:

  > Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'  (ArgumentError)
- I guessed that there was some kind of clash between Rail's default root=>public/index.html and my own routing in config/routes.rb? So I created public/index.html and the root url '/' now serves public/index.html. I want to figure out a way to make it work the 'Rails' way, with the root url routing to controller#action.

2) Static assets are not being served.

- in my layouts/application.html.erb file, I have the Rails default

  > true%>   
  >    true%>
- However, when I fire up the Rails app on elastic beanstalk on production environment, I get:

  > http://myurl.com/javascripts/application.js 404 (Not found)
  >   http://myurl.com/stylesheets/application.css 404 (Not found)
- Interestingly, assets in public/images get served correctly.

Does anyone know the solutions for these problems?

Thank You in advance!

========================= Edit ===========================

I'm using Amazon 64bit Linux with Passenger Standalone

Comment: Can you please tell the exact name solution stack you are using? Is it "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Ruby 2.0 (Puma)" or some other version. Can you try with this latest version?

Comment: I added it to the question!

Comment: Can you try the latest solution stack version for passenger standalone - currently v1.0.3. The exact solution stack name is "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Ruby 2.0 (Passenger Standalone)"?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm using right now, Sorry I wasn't specific enough! And my local dev env is also Ruby 2.0

Comment: For (1) can you try what is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24222282/161628

Comment: I tried many different routes.rb conventions, but none of them worked in the production environment when staged on elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
end
```

Remove or comment out all definitions of '/' (including get '/', match '/', etc.)

**app/controllers/home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render 'index'
  end

end
```

**app/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>HELLO WORLD.</h1>
```

And make sure to delete **public/index.html**.